Getting "Insufficient vpc.amazonaws.com/pod-eni" error with prefix mode enabled with a nitro based instance
I have an EKS cluster on AWS. I'm trying to run many small pods on a single node, which makes  the number of IP addresses the most scarce resource. Therefore I chose an instance type that is nitro based and has trunking capabilities (r6g.medium) according to the limits.go file suggested by AWS documentation and enabled prefix mode by setting ENABLE_PREFIX_DELEGATION to true, and followed this article to recycle nodes and enable the feature.
When I run kubectl describe for the cluster node, I can see these lines:
Capacity:
  cpu:                        1
  ephemeral-storage:          20949996Ki
  memory:                     8006364Ki
  pods:                       98
  vpc.amazonaws.com/pod-eni:  4

aws-node pod shows these logs:
Installed /host/opt/cni/bin/aws-cni
Installed /host/opt/cni/bin/egress-cni
time="2024-11-13T05:55:34Z" level=info msg="Starting IPAM daemon... "
time="2024-11-13T05:55:34Z" level=info msg="Checking for IPAM connectivity... "
time="2024-11-13T05:55:36Z" level=info msg="Copying config file... "
time="2024-11-13T05:55:36Z" level=info msg="Successfully copied CNI plugin binary and config file."

There are total 11 pods running now including the system pods e.g. aws-node, and when I deploy another pod, it sits in "Pending" state and says this:

0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient vpc.amazonaws.com/pod-eni. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.

Node events say these:
Controller
  Normal   ControllerVersionNotice  9m19s                  vpc-resource-controller  The node is managed by VPC resource controller version v1.4.10
  Normal   NodeReady                9m18s                  kubelet                  Node ip-x-x-x-x.x.compute.internal status is now: NodeReady
  Normal   NodeTrunkInitiated       9m15s                  vpc-resource-controller  The node has trunk interface initialized successfully

My expectation was as long as hardware resources is not an issue, the node should accept up to 98 pods. What am I missing here?
Edit: I was able to access the ipamd logs on the instance:
"msg":"Instance supports Prefix Delegation"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2024-11-13T05:30:43.235Z","caller":"ipamd/ipamd.go:380","msg":"Prefix Delegation enabled true"}
{"level":"debug","ts":"2024-11-13T05:30:43.235Z","caller":"ipamd/ipamd.go:385","msg":"Start node init"}
{"level":"debug","ts":"2024-11-13T05:30:43.235Z","caller":"ipamd/ipamd.go:2270","msg":"max prefix 3 max ips 48"}
{"level":"debug","ts":"2024-11-13T05:30:43.235Z","caller":"ipamd/ipamd.go:400","msg":"Max ip per ENI 48 and max prefixes per ENI 3"
...
{"level":"debug","ts":"2024-11-13T09:35:43.766Z","caller":"ipamd/ipamd.go:1283","msg":"ENI eni-xxx cannot be deleted because it is primary"}
{"level":"debug","ts":"2024-11-13T09:35:43.766Z","caller":"ipamd/ipamd.go:1283","msg":"ENI eni-yyy cannot be deleted because it is a trunk ENI"}

